# Streaming audio file directly from blob

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, audio

So I am working on this project where I want to store an audio file in a `LARGEBLOB` on a database, the size of the file is limited to about 10MB, and be able to load the data through a java servlet that allows for playing of the media file.

Most of the sources I have been able to find suggests storing it locally, however, I want to avoid this solution based on the fact that I'd like to rebuild the website somewhere completely different and not have to rely on the folder structure to be the same.

The issues that I am encountering area mainly that the web browser misinterprets the binary data provided by the servlet. It manages to retrieve that it is an audio file of some sort, however; it is unable to determine the type of audio file, which leads me to believe that the servlet is either not providing enough data, or that I am not doing enough to instruct the web browser on how to play the file.

For example, if I have a file `audio.mp3` which I have uploaded to the database into a table `Tracks` and stored in a column `TrackFile`. Assuming the query of selecting the right song from the table, what data would the servlet need to provide in order for the browser to play the file when accessing the servlet. Currently when I load the servlet, the browser seems to assume that the type is `audio/mpeg` instead of `audio/mp3`. The content currently delivered by the servlet also looks something like this:

```
response.setHeader("Content-Type", this.getServletContext().getMimeType(t.getTrackName() + '.' + t.getFileType()));
response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(t.getTrackData().length));
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + t.getTrackName() + '.' + t.getFileType() + "\"");

response.getOutputStream().write(t.getTrackData());
```

where `t` is an object which holds all the data which can be retrieved from the database table about a specific track. The method `getTrackData()` returns a `byte[]` with contents of the column `TrackFile` in it. The source of this method is: [link](https://o7planning.org/en/11067/displaying-image-from-database-with-java-servlet), although I adapted it in order to make it work with audio files, although it doesn't.

Are there any obvious things that I should have caught onto based on the fact that I can't get it to play back the file or is what I want to achieve generally impossible so to say?